# How to tell what files are using a template in blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

In *blade* you can use `@include` to include a *view file* into another one. However I'm editing someone else's project and was wondering if there was a way of find which file has included (`@include(...)`) that file.

For example I have a file called `contact.blade.php` which includes `form.blade.php`. Is there a way to tell that `contact.blade.php` is using `form.blade.php` without going into the file and searching for it?

This becomes a problem when you have a lot of files and want to remove the `@include` from only some of them.

Thanks

Comment: I think you should be able to get around by doing a text search under `resources/views/` with your favourite IDE: `@include('form')` (or whatever your include call looks like). Also, if you are passing vars you can use just the beginning: `@include('form`

Comment: Also, I think [Laravel X-RAY package](https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-view-xray) may come in handy.

Comment: just do a search ... views are always relative to their own root, not the document, so it should be the same string everywhere

Answer (score 0):

The link provided in @include begins from your root views folder (`/resources/views`)

So if in `contact.blade.php` you have `@include('form')` then `form.blade.php` can be found at `/resources/views/form.blade.php`

Hope that helps.